# Wrapping WTMS image & map extent

Tags: openlayers, wmts

I'm using OpenLayers 3 (both v3.4 and v3.5) to display a tiled image from a NASA WMTS server and have a question about using the layer wrapX parameter on a global map.  When I set wrapX=true in the layer specification, I can pan left and right, but the layer image doesn't line up - there's an empty gap between -180 and +180.

Am I missing some simple parameter to tell OL3 to glue the bounds together?

Here's how the map is built:

```
var extent = [-180, -90, 180, 90];
var map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({
        maxResolution: 0.5625,
        projection: ol.proj.get("EPSG:4326"),
        extent: extent,
        center: center_coord,
        zoom: 1,
        maxZoom: 8
    }),
    renderer: ["canvas", "dom"]
});
```

And here's the code to build the layer:

```
var bmng = new ol.source.WMTS({
    wrapX: true,
    url: "http://map1{a-c}.vis.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts-geo/wmts.cgi",
    layer: "BlueMarble_NextGeneration",
    matrixSet: "EPSG4326_500m",
    format: "image/jpeg",
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
        origin: [-180, 90],
        resolutions: [
            0.5625,
            0.28125,
            0.140625,
            0.0703125,
            0.03515625,
            0.017578125,
            0.0087890625,
            0.00439453125,
            0.002197265625
        ],
        matrixIds: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        tileSize: 512
    })
});
layer_bmng = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: bmng,
});
map.addLayer(layer_bmng);
map.addLayer(bmng);
```

Now, it occurs to me that this might be related to another issue.  I note that the default map doesn't actually show the full [-180, 180] longitude extent - on load, the map shows only roughly [-160, 160] although I can pan left/right and see the rest of the map. The HTML and CSS are pretty simple, but I suppose it might be a CSS issue.  The map is in an empty :

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

and the CSS for the map looks like this:

```
#map {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```